# What were the achievements in Vanilla World of Warcraft?

Tags: achievements, world-of-warcraft

What were the achievements in Vanilla WoW?
I know they weren't in the game at the time, but weren't some added that you could no longer get?
A list would be great!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Achievements for vanilla WoW appear under the "legacy" tab in the achievements list. Most of them were retroactively awarded to players once the achievement system was implemented.

I have not been able to find a full list of legacy achievements specific to vanilla. However, you can find vanilla achievements easily enough by searching the wowhead database for legacy achievements with "60" or "classic" in their description. I cannot guarantee that all of them have this identifier though.

Below are links to all of the legacy achievement lists on WoWhead:

[General](https://www.wowhead.com/legacy-achievements)

[Dungeons](https://www.wowhead.com/legacy-dungeon-achievements)

[Raids](https://www.wowhead.com/legacy-raid-achievements)

[Professions](https://www.wowhead.com/legacy-profession-achievements)

[Player vs. Player](https://www.wowhead.com/legacy-pvp-achievements)

[Currency](https://www.wowhead.com/legacy-currencies-achievements)

[Expansion Features](https://www.wowhead.com/legacy-expansion-feature-achievements)

Scroll through these or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and look for "60" or "classic". Off the top of my head, I know you'll find some vanilla achievements related to pvp, dungeons, and raids. For example, if you browse the legacy PvP achievements and search for "60", you will find achievements that rewarded titles based on the highest achieved PvP rank during vanilla, such as [Blood Guard](https://www.wowhead.com/achievement=449/blood-guard). There are also some dungeon and raid achievements, such as [Onyxia](https://www.wowhead.com/achievement=684/onyxias-lair-level-60).

**Note:** As mentioned in the comments, some of these achievements were actually attainable after Vanilla.

Comment: Seems to only be "Onyxia's Lair (Level 60) -Defeat the classic, level 60 version of Onyxia.", "Tabard of the Protector -Obtained a Tabard of the Protector from the Dark Portal event.", and a bunch of PvP titles.

Comment: There are also things like the Scarab Lord title (opening of AQ) . Not sure if there's an achievement for that, but there should be one.

Comment: @dly Achievements that were limited to only very few players aren't listed unless you actually have said achievement.  Scarab Lord was only available within a 10 hour window of the first person to bang the gong on each server, sooooo.....  (If it wasn't clear, yes there is an [achievement](https://www.wowhead.com/achievement=416/scarab-lord) for it)

Comment: @boogie1488 None of them were really achievements, they were more feats of strength.  Achievements were added for level 60 content (e.g. clear Blackwing Lair) when achievements were introduced in WotLK, but you had to go back and actually re-clear the raid...unless you still had some drops from the end boss in your inventory, where you got retroactive credit.  It was mostly event-based Feats of Strength like do the gates of AQ questline or get the tabard during the 1.11 Naxx invasion.  Not many.

Comment: @boogie1488 The Onyxia one was added when they redid Onyxia as a mid-Cataclysm (I think) raid.  You could get that achievement all the way up until the raid was removed well after Vanilla, and certainly above a level 60.

Comment: Legacy achievements are not specifically from Classic WoW, they are more old/outdated and perhaps unobtainable achievements. Definitely not specifically for Classic.